# How to rename a zero-padded file sequence efficiently in ZSH?

Tags: find, zsh

I have a picture sequence named with zero-padded numbers like so:

```
/path/to/file_07469.jpx
/path/to/file_07470.jpx
/path/to/file_07471.jpx
/path/to/file_07472.jpx
/path/to/file_07473.jpx
/path/to/file_07474.jpx
/path/to/file_07475.jpx
/path/to/file_07476.jpx
/path/to/file_07477.jpx
/path/to/file_07478.jpx
/path/to/file_07479.jpx
/path/to/file_07480.jpx
/path/to/file_07481.jpx
/path/to/file_07482.jpx
```

This is just an extract. It is thousands of files. I’d like to rename all files from a certain number on, adding / subtracting X. I’d love to use `find` with a `regex`.

```
#!/bin/zsh

shift=-1000
seqnumstart="$(echo "$1" | grep -Eo "\d+")"
bn="$(basename $1)"
bbn="$(echo "${bn%_*}")"
ext="$(echo "${bn##*.}")"

find "$(dirname $1)" -name "$bbn*$ext" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    seqnum="$(echo "$file" | grep -Eo "\d+")"
    seqnum="$(echo "${seqnum#"${seqnum%%[!0]*}"}")"

    if [[ "$seqnum" -ge "$seqnumstart" ]]; then
        seqnumnew=$(($seqnum + $shift))
        seqnumnew=$(printf %05d $seqnumnew)
        filenew="$(echo $file | sed -E 's [0-9]+ '$seqnumnew' g')"
        mv "$file" "$filenew"
    fi

done
```

How can I improve my code? It is very slow. Im on a Mac (zsh).

Comment: can you post the expected output as well.

Comment: Done. `zsh` it is.

Comment: @forit: For each input file, you are creating plenty of child processes. No wonder that it takes time. For instance, calculating `seqnum` uses currently 3 child processes, although it could be done entirely within the zsh parent process. Same for calculating `seqnumnew` and `filenew`.

Answer (score 1):

`zmv` is a utility in `zsh` that can do a lot of filename manipulation and looping for you. Try this:

```
zmv -n 'p/file_(<7000-7999>).jpx' 'p/file_$(printf "%05d" $(($1 - 1000))).jpx'
```

Some of the pieces:

- `zmv`: an autoload function; use `autoload -Uz zmv` to make it available (this is usually added to `.zshrc`).
- `-n`: no-op. With this option, zmv will just print what would have happened, giving you an idea if the command is correct. Remove this to actually `mv` the files.
- `(...)`: grouping operator for zmv. This identifies sections in the name that you want to change; this section is referenced in the 'to' argument as `$1`.
- `<7000-7999>`: glob operator for a range. Note that leading zeroes are not always required.
- `$(printf "%05d" ...)`: zero-padding.
- `$((...))`: arithmetic.
- `$1`: reference to the parenthetical value in the 'from' argument'. This is where `zmv`'s magic happens - this is substituted for each matching filename.

As you likely know, you'll need to do the renaming in groups or in a specific order to avoid trying to change a name to a name that already exists. `zmv` will usually halt when it encounters collisions like that.

Comment: Looks great! I’m going to give it a try. Looks like `zmv` is not available out of the box on macOS though.

Comment: @florit Whoops! Forgot that it is an autoload function. I added some more to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is much faster:

```
#!/bin/zsh

shift=1000

seqnumstart="$(echo "$1" | grep -Eo "\d+")"
lastfile="$(find "$(dirname $1)" -name "*.jpx" | sort | tail -1)"
seqnumend="$(echo "$lastfile" | grep -Eo "\d+")"

bn="$(basename $1)"
bbn="$(echo "${bn%_*}")"

#extension
ext="$(echo "${bn##*.}")"

#basepath before the padded number
bp="$(echo "${1%_*}")"

function buildpath {
    echo "$bp"_"$1"."$ext"
}

for i in {$seqnumstart..$seqnumend}
do
   unpad="$(echo $i | sed 's/^0*//')"
   seqnumnew="$(($unpad + $shift))"
   seqnumnewpad="$(printf %05d $seqnumnew)"

   op="$(buildpath "$i")"
   np="$(buildpath "$seqnumnewpad")"

   mv "$op" "$np"
done
```